# PHP on IIS won't connect to Oracle SQL (oci_)

Tags: php, oracle, iis

I am attempting to get PHP on IIS connected to Oracle SQL.

I have:

1. Installed IIS Server Role
2. Installed PHP
3. Downloaded Oracle Instant Client to C:\instantclient
4. Added C:\instantclient to PATH System Variable
5. Added php_oci8.dll to php.ini and checked that PHP is actually using this php.ini
6. Restarted server

I am still getting error messages like:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\oracle.php on line 13

I've spent days on this and can't see anything else to try.

I've searched 30+ hours online, and everyone says to do the same thing; what I've already done. I'm banging my head against the desk!

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure which oracle version you're using but with Oracle 12c libraries use extension=php_oci8_12c.dll and what does phpinfo give you?

Comment: @Daan I am using an old version, Oracle 8i. I am using the same Instant Client version as we have working on our Linux server (just I downloaded the Windows version). `phpinfo()` does not show anything about OCI8.

Comment: Than you it's not enabled of course.

Comment: @Daan Yes I know, that's why I asked. I don't understand what I've missed. I've followed every single instruction I've found.

Comment: How did you add it to php.ini? Usually its already there you just need to uncomment the line.

Comment: @Daan I just uncommented it and restarted IIS.